# How to check if JSON Object Key's Value is Key Object?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "key_one": {
        "key_two": {
            "value": 1,
            "data": 1
        }
    }
}
```

How to check if the `value` of `key_one` is an `object`, not `value` it self?

@edit Validated to provide minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof input.key_one` will tell you if it is an object:

```js
const input = {
  "key_one": {
    "key_two": {
      "value": 1
    }
  }
};

console.log(typeof input.key_one);
```

Output:

```
object
```

Note: If you want to make that distinction between object and array you can use this:

```
Array.isArray(val) ? 'array' : typeof val
```

Comment: it will tell if its an object for each key and value inside of JSON, am I right? I want to determine if the value is an object. Also without using the key name it self.

Comment: You can get the key names by traversing the object with `Object.keys()`. Drill down recursively if a value is an object.

Comment: thanks, I think I will manage from there. Seems like I overthink it a little

Comment: typeof is a good solution but it will return "object" for Array as well, so this  may cause issues if data type changes in future.

Comment: @LokeshYadav: Yup. If you want to make that distinction you can use: `Array.isArray(val) ? 'array' : typeof val`

Comment: @PeterThoeny You are absolutely right. Intent was to keep additional checks &. balances in code before adopting a solution.